# how to get varaiable if only have more than 3 letters javascript

Tags: javascript, match, timedelay

```
var result="stackoverflow";
var string="22342st";

if(more than 3 letters)
{
var new=data;
}
```

1)how I can get variable if only have more than

using match() (function )  in javascript

2)what if I do getting variable in for time delay 
some (because of TCP connection)

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.length` property to check string length is greater than 3 or not.

```
var result = "stackoverflow";

if(result.length > 3)
{
   //Your business logic goes here
}
```

if you want to check only character counts in string is greater than three then you can try below code

```js
var input = "45749ce";

var result = input.match(/[a-zA-Z]/gi);

if(result.length > 3)
{
   //Your business logic goes here
   console.log(`${result} length is greater than 3`);
}
```

Comment: using length what if i have mixed character   45749ce

Answer (score 1):

That should work

```
var myRegEx = /[a-zA-Z(.+)]{3}/g;
var myString="22342st";

if(myString.match(myRegEx)!==null)
{

}
```

Also

```
myString.match(myRegEx)
```

will return an array of matched values, so you can work with them if needed.

Comment: do you have any idea about getting values delay ...

and i want get those values in same variable

Answer (score 0):

**To find the more than three letter in variable using match you have to need regex**

```
([a-zA-Z0-9)]){3,}
```

**code how looks like**

```
var result="stackoverflow";
var string="22342st";
  var res = string.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9)]){3,}/g);

  if(res!=null){

//here what you want


  }
```